# Caixa com borda e um título sobre a borda superior

Tags: html, css

Existe algum estilo próprio no CSS ou tag HTML onde consigo o efeito como mostrado na imagem abaixo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Seria um `aside` com uma borda de `1px` e a palavra "Realização" centralizada sobre a borda superior, mas que a borda por baixo do texto não apareça, conforme a imagem.

Existe algo no CSS ou HTML que faça isso de forma automática?

Código que tenho:

```css
/* estilos apenas como exemplo,
para mostrar o fundo preto e o texto centralizado*/
body{
   background: #000;
   color: #fff;
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<aside class="realiza"> 
   <p>Realização:</p>
   Qualquer texto aqui
</aside>
```

Comment: Se tu não sabe, quem é que vai saber? : )

Comment: isso aqui > http://jsfiddle.net/daRch/ já é um começo!!

Comment: Não estará à procura da etiqueta `<fieldset>` ?

Comment: Quase chego lá, só faltou uma borracha nas bordas laterais que estão passando pra cima da borda horizontal superior.  http://jsfiddle.net/s0b5auqs/

Comment: Você colocou aside, isso atrapalhou

Comment: como vou apagar aquelas pontas das bordas pra cima?

Comment: difícil vai ser background #000

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Tanto faz.

Comment: Na resposta kkkkk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A etiqueta [`<fieldset>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset) permite criar essa caixa com contorno à volta, e a etiqueta `<legend>` que fica dentro define o que aparece no topo como "titulo".

Veja o exemplo:

```css
/* estilos apenas como exemplo,
para mostrar o fundo preto e o texto centralizado*/
body{
   background: #000;
   color: #fff;
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="realiza"> 
   <legend>Realização:</legend>
   Qualquer texto aqui
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Se for num aside ...**

```css
body{
   background: #000;
   color: #fff;
}


.realiza{
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: relative;

  

}

.realiza div {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: -10px;
  left: 0;

}

.realiza div span{
   background: #000;
  padding: 0 15px;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="div"><aside class="realiza">
   <div><span>Realização:</span></div>
   <p>Qualquer texto aqui</p>
</aside></div>
```